# Exim Route based on Email Header

Tags: email, routing, exim

I am currently crafting an Exim Router to manually route all emails to a user's Spam Box that have a certain header in it.

The following condition works :

```
condition = ${if match{$h_X-Spam-Status:}{\N^Yes\N}{true}{false}}
```

Here's the email header that it is matching :

> X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=20.4

I have another condition, that is on another router, that the conditions are failing to match, despite them being almost identical :

`condition = ${if match{$h_X-Recommended-Action:}{\N^reject\N}{true}{false}}`

Here would be the Email header that the second condition is supposed to match  :

> X-Recommended-Action: reject

Would I be missing anything in my condition that is causing the condition not to match?

Comment: Is that extra colon a typo?

Comment: Hi Jacob, yeah that would be a typo when creating this post. oops.

Comment: As far as you at the very beginning my advise is to move LDA and mailsorting from the `exim` to the IMAP server, probably `dovecot`. Its `sieve` is highly configurable and your users will get an access to the  `managesieve` so they can write their own rules for mail sorting.

Comment: I have no experience in "sieve" at this point in time.  But I'll search it up and update if it is indeed good to go.